# create failed for database 'project'

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am creating a new db in SQL Server 2012 Express edition and I get this error when I trying to create a db create permission denied in database 'master'. I am right clicking database and clicking create new.

I know this is probably a very rookie issue but I will be happy to hear any solutions to this issue. Seen some similar posts but I couldn't find one that would work for SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant create database access to the user you are trying to create with.

```
use master; GRANT CREATE DATABASE to <insert_your_user_here>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help but i got this error Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself. this is what i typed in use master; GRANT CREATE DATABASE to "MyPcsName\MyLoginNameOnMyPc" thanks for any help

Comment: Sounds like your user is missing creation permissions altogether. Do you have access to the SA account?

Comment: I logged into my main account that has admin permissions and it worked but on the user account i am using it doesn't work any way i can get these permissions on both accounts? Thanks for the help

Comment: You can grant everything to your user account from the admin account. So log in to the admin, then Google different permissions that you can grant. There are quite a few of them that you might want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide access to user to create DB

```
ALTER USER username CREATEDB;
```